# Geofence exit region delegate method triggered even device in stable position iOS (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, geofencing

I have implemented geofence in my app. CLRegion radius is 200m. CLRegion boundary Exitregion delegate method triggers even when the device is in a stable position within CLRegion region.

Here is my code

```
locationmanager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationmanager.delegate = self;
locationmanager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationmanager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationmanager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

if (locationmanager.locationServicesEnabled) {
    [locationmanager startUpdatingLocation];
}

CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(13.051404,
                                                           80.179970);
CLRegion *bridge = [[CLCircularRegion alloc]initWithCenter:center
                                                    radius:200.0
                                                identifier:@"Bridge"];


[locationmanager startMonitoringForRegion:bridge];
[locationmanager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
          fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"location notific %f %f",oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    NSLog(@"location notific2 %f %f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
   [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];


}
```

Can anyone suggest me is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You’re not using the geofence delegate method. You’re using the standard location delegate method. Search the docs for locationManager:didEnterRegion: and didExitRegion methods

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using this locationManager:didEnterRegion: and didExitRegion methods only.                                 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region                                                                                                   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region

Comment: Those methods aren't in your code sample, you only show `-locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`

Comment: Sorry for that. but is there any solution for my issue. didExitRegion triggers when the device is in a stable position within CLRegion region.